# Trying to make an https call through an ssh tunnel (to bypass a firewall)

Tags: ssh, https, ssh-tunnel

I have a bastion server which has access to another server which is otherwise unavailable to the outside world.

I am trying to make it so that I can make an https web call to hit an endpoint on the unavailable server from my localhost for testing purposes. To do this, I have been trying to follow this answer: https://superuser.com/a/1447340/441810

So I edited my /etc/hosts file and added:

`127.0.0.1 <firewalled-box>`

And then I created the tunnel:

`ssh -L 443:<firewalled-box>:443 me@<bastion>`

However, when I make the web call on my local machine...

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' https://<firewalled-box>/some/path/somewhere/fancy
```

I get:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to <firewalled-box> port 443: Connection refused
```

Comment: I do think you will have better luck using a non-standard port. also make sure the tunnel is on 127.0.0.1, not 127.0.1.1 or any of the other addresses in the loopback range. Try `netstat -ntlup | grep <portnum>` to verify the tunnel is connected and your local port is in a listening state on the address you expect it to be. There is also a question about your httpd and TLS and firewall configuration on the remote target. lots of places this could go wrong. confirm that the site loads via 127.0.0.1 on the target box to confirm its working. also do you have a proxy server in play? good luck.

Comment: Are you running `ssh` as a normal user? Because you cannot bind to port 443 unless you are root.

Answer (score 0):

#### Diagnosis

`Connection refused` means `curl` was not able to connect to whatever it tried to connect to. In your case it tried to connect to your (local) SSH client, unless you did something wrong with `/etc/hosts` and `curl` actually tried to connect to the real (or fake-but-wrong) `<firewalled-box>`.

I assume `curl` tried to connect to your SSH client. It seems your `ssh` was not listening or the communication was blocked.

How do I know the problem is between `curl` and your `ssh`, not (or at least not yet) between the SSH server and `<firewalled-box>`?

It's about how port forwarding with SSH works. In case of local forwarding a connection to SSH client needs to be established before the SSH server tries to connect to the target machine. If the latter connection fails then the former will be terminated. But because the former connection has already been *established* in the first place, the connecting process (`curl` in your case) will print something like `Connection reset by peer`, certainly not `Connection refused`.

In your case `Connection refused` indicates the connection initiated by `curl` couldn't be established.

---

#### Solution

The problem may be because non-privileged users [cannot listen on ports lower than `1024`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16564/108618). If you run `ssh -L …` and the port cannot be used, some `ssh` implementations will refuse to connect to the SSH server at all, but some will only print a warning and connect anyway. The warning might pass unnoticed if `<bastion>` cleared the console or printed a long welcome message.

Use [`-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes`](https://superuser.com/q/352268/432690) to be sure your `ssh` listens upon connection.

If low port number is the culprit then running `ssh` as root will help, although I don't recommend running `ssh` as root.

Maybe all you need is to use a higher number locally, like `-L 1443:<firewalled-box>:443`. Then `curl` should connect to `https://<firewalled-box>:1443/…`.

Note formally `<firewalled-box>` in `-L` should be a name/address understood by the `<bastion>` machine, while `<firewalled-box>` in `curl` invocation should be understood by your local machine (thanks to the modified `/etc/hosts`).

---

#### Alternative

I suggest dynamic port forwarding, SOCKS.

- Remove `127.0.0.1 <firewalled-box>` from your `/etc/hosts`.
- Invoke `ssh -ND 7654 me@<bastion>`.
- Run `curl` with `-x socks5://localhost:7654`. If you use `<firewalled-box>` in the address passed to `curl`, it will have to resolve *locally* to an IP address valid *remotely*; so possibly you will need to modify `/etc/hosts` anyway.

More details about `-D` in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/q/1308495/432690).

Comment: The problem with the sock5 solution is that ultimately I am not going to use curl, but rather execute code locally which is making a call to the <firewalled-vox> host, so that's why I had that in /etc/hosts, to try to "alias" the host to localhost, so that I don't need to reference "localhost" anywhere when the web call is made.

Comment: Thanks @KamilMaciorowski for pointing out my error. I deleted my previous answer since this covers everything.